# What is "folded SMA" package of SMD?

Tags: diodes, surface-mount, packages, drawing

There are three types of package in specification: SMA, Folded SMA and Clip SMA.
The link for datasheet: [SK32A](http://www.taiwansemi.com/products/datasheet/SK32A%20SERIES_T1705.pdf)

What is the differences between them ???

[image: Three types of SMA package]

I suspect, that Folded SMA it is SMAF, but I am not sure.

The SMA and SMAF drawings:

[image: SMA type]
[image: SMAF type]

Comment: In the datasheet you linked, there is only *one* package drawing, which corresponds to the standard (big) SMA. So I don't think "folded" and "clip" SMA are that different from this one. But I don't have the real answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also received the answer from Taiwan Semiconductor.

@CL, is right it is just different production lines. And all types has the same dimensions, mentioned in datasheet.

Also want to noticed that "Folded SMA" not the same than "SMAF".

There are some pictures of SMA, F(olded) SMA, Matrix SMA, Clip SMA:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I asked them. They said:

> These are only different production lines.

I also got a PDF (not published on the Taiwan Semiconductor web site for reasons I'm not going to speculate about) that shows the differences down to the last µm, but all variants (SMA, F(olded) SMA, Matrix SMA, Clip SMA) match the SMA specification in the datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

SMA is the standard lowest cost.  SMAF is half the height (Folded)
Some are long lead time.  These are stock in some places.  SK32A-LTP
Both use same footprint.